# JQuery - ScrollTop locks the scrollbar

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with the scrollbar locking up, [a demo of my issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/QzJbT/2/).

The issue is that when you click onto 'I'm New' and that is using 'ScrollTop' to scroll to the element, the scroll bar locks for a few seconds. Is this normal?

I'm hoping for an easy fix or an easy alternative (here's hoping).

Comment: Do you notice this issue only in jsfiddle, or on your server as well?

Comment: I notice it on my server as well. :)

Comment: Well I do apologize that I don't know what is wrong, but as an answer to "Is this normal?", I say no. I have done jQuery animations similar to this one and not any any problems with the scroll-bar locking up on  me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the following from the jQuery

```
 $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#new_content").offset().top
            }, 1000);
```

From the   `$("#new_link").click(`
, and all the items seam to work and there is no locking in the scrollbar